# Group Policy drive maps fail with Error Code: 0x80070043

Tags: group-policy, server-message-block, netbios, mappeddrive

I'm running a Server 2008 R2 domain with all Windows 7 x64 bit client machines.
All drives are mapped using Group Policy.  Which were previously on a NAS
 We just built a new, huge, fast server.  So I'm in the process of migrating all the network drives from the NAS to the new fileserver(fs).

The old drive maps were mapped using group policy so I just went in and updated to the new server and selected the "Replace" option.  But the drives just plain do not map.  I do an RSOP on my machine and the error for the drive map is:
Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x80070043)

The other odd thing, though it may or may not have anything to do with it, is that the winning GPO shown is shown with its SID instead of its name.  The SID is correct though.

Accessing the shares through Explorer works fine, and mapping them manually works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Chris

Comment: Looks like you're having bigger domain issues.  Showing an SID instead of the "display name" is a sign that you're unable to do lookups.  This might be why you cannot connect to network shares as well.

Comment: Yes, that is one of my concerns.  But where do I start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: look in event logs for other warnings/errors... dcdiag/replmon... check dns issues... etc...   long list of things to check... sorry there's not a silver-bullet for this type of problem.  Not even a silver shot-gun.  darn.

Comment: I was hoping maybe you had something in mind I hadn't thought of.  Event Logs are clean, DNS works perfectly everywhere but in GP apparently dcdiag does show an error but I'm pretty sure its unrelated, I'm just going to persue that and see where it gets me

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So both errors in dcdiag were completely unrelated, and both are cleared up now as well... so at least there's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I completely forgot to post what the solution was!

It ended up being something incredibly dumb.  My habits in using the command line betrayed me!

The short version is that in a GPO, do NOT use quotes in the paths!  Even if they have spaces, no quotes.

Comment: Similar and equally as frustrating... I just spent a few hours troubleshooting this as well to discover that you also don't end the shared path with a slash "\"  So, in my case, \\domain.com\share\ was what I entered and what I really needed was \\domain.com\share without the trailing slash. :'(

Answer (score 1):

0x80070043 is "The network name cannot be found.". You can use err.exe to translate these error codes. err.exe is at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=985

Could be a name resolution issue. You dont say whether explorer based access was done using IP address or name.

Might want to look at the group policy preference debug logs as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/07/18/enabling-group-policy-preferences-debug-logging-using-the-rsat.aspx to see what it reveals for drive maps extension.

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening up the GPM mmc? Are you doing so from your client or from the DC?  SID Translation problems, try remoting into the DC and running GPM from there to see if it still fails to translate.  If it still fails, try re-creating (or restoring) the GPO.